# best way to do the head (eye parts)

Tags: bevel

Hi im failing to do this figure.. i could do it but i want to do real clean low poly modeling ...

whats the best way to Archive the head and the eye part (marked red) ???

i tried to extrude a few areas inside and used subsurface modiefier but it looks not good.. i need sharper edges.. i think its done with bevel but i cant get it to work... any help would be great..thx[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you can achieve this: [image]

Just like you did, I extruded the eyes and the mouth inwards, I marked the boundaries as 100% bevel ( Item -> Mean Bevel Weight 1) and added a Bevel modifier with a Limit Method -> Angle. That is all, just tweak the Bevel Amount.

Comment: thx man i will check it out in a bit when i get home , sound good so far :D

Comment: ok this method is basically the old method i used :D just without bevels... 

but the outer eye socket shape is not possible this way... 

after asking somewhere else somebody told me knife projection is the way to go... after googling it it looks like thats it...

Comment: i have absolutely no clue what you mean.